# Choose train data if an identifier is in the range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a database with 83 firms. I choose 80% of firms for train set with the following code:

```
mask = np.random.rand(83) <0.8
df['gvkey'].drop_duplicates()[mask] 
The outcome:

24       2086
48       3011
76       5020
88       6266
100      6730
        ...  
880    156617
890    157954
902    160607
917    164266
926    264414
Name: gvkey, Length: 67, dtype: int64
```

Where gvkey is a unique firm identifier, but each identifier has 10 firm-year observations.

I want a new column in the original dataset. When gvkey is one of the 67 gvkeys (train set firms), the columns takes "train", otherwise "test".

Just an idea:

```
df['train'] = np.where(for df['gvkey'] in df['gvkey'].drop_duplicates()[mask_1], 'train', 'test')
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html) to select only 67 gvkeys on the unique gvkeys obtained with `drop_duplicates`, then use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and `astype` to get 1 if the gvkey is in the 67 from the sample and 0 otherwise.

```
df['train'] = df['gvkey'].isin(df['gvkey'].drop_duplicates()
                                 .sample(n=67).to_numpy()).astype(int)
```

Note that in `sample`, you can use `frac=0.8` instead of `n=67`, but in this case it picks only 66 values

Edit: sorry I mixed up things and realized you wanted train and test and not 1 and 0, so similar, you can do

```
df['train'] = np.where(df['gvkey'].isin(df['gvkey'].drop_duplicates()
                                  .sample(n=67).to_numpy()), 
                       'train','test')
```

That said having 1 or 0 in this column would be easier to use later.

Comment: Thanks Ben, it produced exactly what I wanted. The first with 0 and 1 would suffice. I just needed a distinction between two.